# Tables are not dropped when rolling back migration

Tags: database-migration, knex.js, rollback

When I execute the rollback command from Knex it only removes rows from the `knex_migrations` table but not the tables created by the migrations.

I'm using MySQL, but the same happens with SQLite3.

GitHub repository: https://github.com/patrick-vieira/knex-rollback

First migration:

```
import * as Knex from 'knex';

export async function up(knex: Knex): Promise<void>{
  return knex.schema.createTable('users', table => {

    table.increments('id').primary();
    
    table.string('name').notNullable();
    table.string('avatar').notNullable();
    table.string('whatsapp').notNullable();
    table.string('bio').notNullable();
  });
}

// roolback
export async function down(knex: Knex): Promise<void> {
  knex.schema.dropTable('users');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You always need to return the result of your `knex` operation from the `up` and `down` functions. If you look at the example I've edited into your question, you'll see that you use the `return` statement in `up`, but not in `down`.

Further, migrations return a schema builder (not `void`). I don't normally write migrations in TS, but I think what you're looking for, signature-wise, is something like:

```
import Knex, { SchemaBuilder } from 'knex'

export const up = (knex: Knex): SchemaBuilder => {
  return knex.schema.createTable( // ... etc ...
}
```

A trick to ensure you always remember to return the result is to leverage arrow function auto-return:

```
export const up = (knex: Knex) => knex.schema.createTable(
  // ... etc ...
```

Comment: Since up and down are async functions here they returns a promise implicitly, but in that case at least migration command must be awaited before returning. `await knex.schema.dropTable('users');`. Now the command is only built, but never executed.

Comment: So I may have confused the issue here by removing my oringinal `async` in an edit, but I think the version I have in the current edit is correct (no async) so long as `return` is used, yes?

Comment: Yep, what ever function that returns a promise which is not resolved until all the migration queries are ran is fine 

Comment: Thankyou @Rich Churcher and Mikael! the only thing that i was missing was the return on the down function, now it is working correctly.